# ClaimsAuthenticationManager in parallel with RoleManagerModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, wif, claims-based-identity

I'm mixing classic Membership/RoleManager security setup with new WIF 4.5 API for testing purposes. I have implemented two classes that I have breakpoints set on:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
    {
        public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
        {
// Breakpoint here is hit 1st
            if (!incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
            }
            return TransformPrincipal(incomingPrincipal);
        }

        private ClaimsPrincipal TransformPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
        {
            // this breakpoint is hit last
            ClaimsIdentity newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("Custom");
            newIdentity.AddClaims(incomingPrincipal.Claims);
            // I add some additional claims
            ClaimsPrincipal newPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentity);
            return newPrincipal;
        }
    }

public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        // breakpoint here is hit 2nd
        if(username == "me") return new string [] { "Lead", "Developer" };
        return new string[] {};
    }

    #region Not implemented

    // bunch of not implemented methods

    #endregion
}
```

Now result is quite fine, I get mixed ClaimsPrincipal that has both Name claim, Role claims and claims that I've added in TransformPrincipal method.

However, debugging breakpoints are hit in completely weird order:

1) Breakpoint at the beginning of Authenticate method is hit first

2) Breakpoint at the beginning of GetRolesForUser is hit second

3) Breakpoing at the beginning of TransformPrincipal is hit last

Is this just Visual Studio issue or there is an atomic chance that Authenticate might complete before GetRolesForUser is called?

How are RoleManagerModule and ClaimsAuthenticationManager working in the pipeline? In parallel or there is sequential order? Can mixing the two be an issue?

**EDIT:**

```
void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal transformedPrincipal = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.ClaimsAuthenticationManager.Authenticate(null, ClaimsPrincipal.Current);

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = transformedPrincipal;
            HttpContext.Current.User = transformedPrincipal;
        }
```

**EDIT:**

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="Tests.CustomMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Tests.CustomRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>


<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <claimsAuthenticationManager type="Tests.CustomAuthenticationManager, Tests"/>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
```

Comment: When you enter the ClaimsAuthenticationManager - do you have a RolePrincipal. IIRC there is some lazy loading going on which would explain why GetRolesForUser is called somewhere in between. I would dump RoleManager altogether and simply add roles in the authNmanager.

Comment: Excellent point Dominick, the principal that is passed into Authenticate method is indeed RolePrincipal. Does this mean that RoleManagerModule is constructing the principal earlier in the pipeline (before ClaimsAuthenticationManager) but Role claims are added later in the parallel? Or are they retrieved only when they are accessed (i.e. when I'm transforming the RolePrincipal to my principal and iterating through existing Role claims)?

Comment: I think they are retrieved when accessed. Pretty messy. I removed the role manager module altogether.

Comment: That is what I plan to do eventually, I was just testing out things when I've encountered this. Thanks for the assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

These two are rather not meant to be used together. SAM role management suppresses forms authentcation role management and as I suspect, your role provider is just enabled in `web.config`.

I haven't tested this under 4.5 but I don't believe it changed. In 4.0 the authentication manager fires **only** if a user is not yet authenticated or current user is established with another authentication module. The latter could happen unexpectedly when you issue both cookies, the forms cookie and the sam cookie. Take a look at my blog post on that

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/09/sessionauthenticationmodule-and-dynamic.html

Although I don't know why the breakpoint at the authenticate gets hit first, SAM would notice that your user is `RolePrincipal` with `FormsIdentity` and would try to make a `ClaimsPrincipal` out of it and then call the authentication manager.

**Edit**: after all you provided, I still have a slight problem regarding the order. Although Dominick suspects roles are lazy loaded, I can't confirm this by recompiling the BCL. Rather, the `RolePrincipal` seems to eagerly add role claims in the constructor (the internal `AttachRoleClaims` method in the `RolePrincipal` class).

No matter how I look into it, I believe the `GetRolesForUser` should be called first, as this is `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` passed to the `Authenticate`.

If your `RoleProvider` creates the `RolePrincipal` in advance, the `AttachRoleClaims` would be called and roles would be enumerated with the `RoleProvider.GetRolesForUser`.

If your `RoleProvider` doesn't create the `RolePrincipal` in advance, the `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` would and this leads to the same execution path.

**Edit2**: I've found the possible culprit, it is the `RoleClaimProvider::Claims` method that is internally used by the `AttachRoleClaims`. It is implemented lazily with `yield` which means that until someone actually enumerates role claims, they are not created. This "someone" is your code from the `TransformPrincipal`:

```
     ClaimsIdentity newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("Custom");
     /* this forces the enumeration */
     newIdentity.AddClaims(incomingPrincipal.Claims);
```

However, this would also mean that the `GetRolesForUser` would be called last, from within the `TransformPrincipal`.

Comment: I'm not using SessionAuthenticationModule, only ClaimsAuthenticationManager.

Comment: Sure, this is possible but then your question lacks the details on how you call them, the claims manager and the role provider. You are asking how they work in the pipeline but you haven't described WHICH pipeline (your custom, a builtin, which one, web or not).

Comment: Ok, that's my bad. Basically I'm letting RoleManagerModule to use RoleProvider by defining <roleManager> in web.config. When it comes to ClaimsAuthenticationManager, I'm invoking Authenticate method in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest manually.

Comment: Can you possibly show the code that invokes the `Authenticate`? I have my theory on why you see methods invoked in this particular order but there are some missing points I'd like to fill by verifying what you actually do.

Comment: I've edited my original post and added the code in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest.

Comment: Edited my answer but I would like to see your web.config setup regarding authentication/authorization and federated identity. I would be able to recreate your scenario then and debug it.

Comment: I'll drop web.config later on today together with RoleProvider, stay tuned. This is really an issue worth investigating.

Comment: I've updated my original post with web.config entries that are related to security.Pretty much standard web.config settings.